# Polar equations (further question)

Tags: polar-coordinates

Consider the polar equations of the form $r=a\cos(b\theta)$ and $r=a\sin(b\theta)$. What is the nature of the graphs of these two polar equations and then summarize some generalizations with respect to the nature of the curves generated and the two parameters $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I found out that r=acos(b) and r=asin(b)graphs are the same shapes and sizes if they have the the same a and b value. However, they have different compositions because they are “complementary” to one another in their positions. The graphs are rotated by /4 from each other. Cosinegraphs are usually in contact with the x and y axis. Sinegraphs are usually not in contact with the x and y axis. However, both graphs are in contact with the origin (0,0).

Answer (score 2):

All these questions can be best answered by *plotting* the curves in polar coordinates. First rectangular and next polar plots so we gain insight about polar curve behaviour, how the tip of vector goes around. The polar curve

$$ r= a \sin( b \,\theta) $$

is a ***rose.***

For $b=1$ it is a circle tangent to x-axis at origin. If $b$ is odd integer, it has the same number of petals or lobes. If even integer it has double that many petals. $a$ is maximum radius from origin.

For  non integral $b$ the radius goes around origin indefinitely.

For $cos$ there is a rotation offset of the entire rose.

An addition in the argument gives rise to cardioids.